# Graphviz: tree structure

Tags: graphviz

I want to use graphviz to generate structures tree, left-to-right structure like that (please ignore colors):

[image: Desired outcome]

I came to the conclusion that I need to use invisible nodes to achieve that, my current code looks like that:

```
digraph G { 
  node [ shape="box", width = 2, height = 1, fixedsize=true];
  edge [arrowhead=none];
  nodesep = 1;
  ranksep=0.05;
  splines = ortho;
  rankdir = LR;

  A1 [ shape="box", width = 2, height = 1, fixedsize=true];
  B1 [ shape="box", width = 2, height = 1, fixedsize=true];
  B2 [ shape="box", width = 2, height = 1, fixedsize=true];
  B3 [ shape="box", width = 2, height = 1, fixedsize=true];
  B4 [ shape="box", width = 2, height = 1, fixedsize=true];
  B5 [ shape="box", width = 2, height = 1, fixedsize=true];
  B6 [ shape="box", width = 2, height = 1, fixedsize=true];

  W0 [ shape="circle", width = 0, height = 0, fixedsize=true, label=""];
  W1 [ shape="circle", width = 0, height = 0, fixedsize=true, label=""];
  W2 [ shape="circle", width = 0, height = 0, fixedsize=true, label=""];
  W3 [ shape="circle", width = 0, height = 0, fixedsize=true, label=""];
  W4 [ shape="circle", width = 0, height = 0, fixedsize=true, label=""];
  W5 [ shape="circle", width = 0, height = 0, fixedsize=true, label=""];
  W6 [ shape="circle", width = 0, height = 0, fixedsize=true, label=""];

  subgraph {
    A1 -> W0
    W0 -> W3
    W3 -> W2
    W2 -> W1
    W0 -> W4
    W4 -> W5
    W5 -> W6

    W1 -> B1
    W2 -> B2
    W3 -> B3
    W4 -> B4
    W5 -> B5
    W6 -> B6

    {rank = same; A1;}
    {rank = same; B1; B2; B3; B4; B5; B6;}
    {rank = same; W0; W1; W2; W3; W4; W5; W6;}
  }
}
```

And using dot engine I get:

[image: Current outcome]

My questions:

Can I force certain nodes to take center position (A1)?

Can I force edges to connect to certain places on node's shape border (e.g.: center left)?

Maybe there is a better way to achieve such a tree structure that will have nodes center (I must consider that next layers of the tree can be quite complex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get what you want, you need to

- define the nodes in the order you want to have them drawn (not strictly necessary in the given example here but good practice)
- make sure that the empty nodes are in the same rank (you have that already)
- and connect these empty nodes with each other in the right order (this is the critical item here)

Applying these changes, and simplyfying your code (you may like that or not, this is just how I would do it), I get to

```
digraph G { 
  edge [arrowhead=none];
  nodesep = 1;
  ranksep=0.05;
  splines = ortho;
  rankdir = LR;

  node [ shape="box", width = 2, height = 1, fixedsize=true];
  A1;
  B4 B5 B6 B3 B2 B1;

  node [ shape="point", width = 0, height = 0 ];
  { rank = same; W4 W5 W6 W0 W3 W2 W1 }

  A1 -> W0;
  W4 -> W5 -> W6 -> W0 -> W3 -> W2 -> W1;        /* critical! */
  W1 -> B1;
  W2 -> B2;
  W3 -> B3;
  W4 -> B4;
  W5 -> B5;
  W6 -> B6;
}
```

which yields

[image]

Comment: When cutting and pasting the code to http://www.webgraphviz.com/ (and removing the #... part as it throws a syntax error) the picture is even better (top and bottom "arrows" end in the middle of the box (B4 / B1)). Looks like there are differences between dot versions.

Comment: Thanks, @albert  --  edited to change to the correct comment delimiters `/* comment */`. My dot is probably really a bit old, `graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)`

Comment: Thanks, vaettchen and albert, this is exactly what I needed. Much appreciated.

Comment: W4 to B4 is not in the center of B4. Is there any way to make that better?
Same thing for W1 to B1.